# Azure Kinect and Hololens

Tags: c++, hololens, azurekinect

Is Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK supported on Lattepanda (Windows OS) , Raspberry Pi 4 (Windows ARM OS) and Intel Compute Stick ?
Does Microsoft hololens azure kinect is same as new azure kinect camera?
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- Hololense has exactly the same depth sensors that Azure Kinect has,
  but it is attached to a moving person.
- By having multiple Azure Kinects, looking at the same environments,
  you can get much precise depth sensing. Especially if you are
  covering a bigger area, it's a great idea to have multiple stable
  devices to get the same data information.
- Also, Azure Kinect has a great API called Skelton SDK, you can use
  this to create applications that could be used for educational
  purposes, and other examples for sports, industrial training, etc, or
  to detect injuries before they happen from repetitive actions.

Coming to the one of the platform supportability question: Please refer to this [thread](https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/issues/656#issuecomment-560558094).

> no news about a support for Pi 4 ?
>
> It doesn't meet our GPU requirements

Comment: Please mark helpful responses as Answer, so that it is useful to others as well with a similar question.